# alternatives to the arcTo method?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, trigonometry, kineticjs

I am creating Custom shapes in kinteicjs, with parameters provided at run time.

This shape will include an arc segment. I assume I have to use the arcTo() method to draw this segment, not the arc() method (please correct me if I am wrong).

Finding the correct parameters for the arcTo() method is hell in my opinion. Question: are there libraries / custom js code available somewhere that can be used as an alternative to draw arcs?

Comment: Can you expand on what parameters you do have and why that makes `arcTo` hard to use? What is the desired API here?

Comment: For each arc I know the coordinates of the two extremities, and the radius of the circle. The problem is that these 3 parameters don't map to the parameters of the arcTo function. I'd like to use kineticjs because of its support for layers and animations.

Comment: Do you know in which direction the center of the circle should be? (eg. for points that are on a topleft-bottomright line, is it bottom left or top right?). And how is this info represented?

Comment: the center of the circle can be in both directions. To illustrate the diffculty, here is a fiddle where I tried to trace arcs of circle (without adjacent straight lines), and that proves difficult: http://jsfiddle.net/d22vw/31/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find this link via a Google search:

As I suspected in the question, the arcTo method is not necessary to draw a shape. Just use the arc() method, which has intuitive parameters, to draw arcs and just drop this weird arcTo() stuff.